# jQuery for each identical parent div toggle nested divs if more than 3 using :nth-child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 identical parent `div`s with different content. If parent `div` has more than 3 child `div`s, at the end of the `div` should be displayed "show more" text that would slide all remaining hidden `div`s. I am new to JavaScript and jQuery and I couldn't completely understand selectors. Here is my code:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>   
    <div class="child">4</div> 
    <div class="child">5</div> 
</div>
<span class="showhide">Show-hide</span>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
</div>
<span class="showhide">Show-hide</span>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>   
    <div class="child">4</div> 
</div>
<span class="showhide">Show-hide</span>
```

the result should display like this:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   show-hide
>   
>   1
>   2
>   
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   show-hide

Here is the script:

```
$('.parent div:nth-child(n+4)').hide();

var l = $('.parent div').length;
if (l > 3) {
    $('.showhide').show();
} else {
    $('.showhide').hide();
}

$(".showhide").click(function() {
    $this.find(".parent div:nth-child(n+4)").toggle('slide');
});
```

Only the first part of the code works. It hides `div`s more than 3 in each parent `div`. But the hiding text and toggle don't work.

I have tried multiple variations, like placing the `span` inside parent `div`, changing selectors to `.closest`, also tried to use `:gt()` instead of `:nth-child` but none worked.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/skt60jxg/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do like this,

```
$(".parent").each(function() {
  $(this).find(".child:gt(2)").hide();
});
$(".showhide").click(function() {
  $(this).prev().find(".child:gt(2)").slideToggle();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/188/)

`.gt()` selector will return the elements whose index is greater than the specified parameter

If you want to change the text after toggling, use this code,

```
$(".parent").each(function() {
  $(this).find(".child:gt(2)").hide();
});
$(".showhide").click(function() {
  var obj = this;
  $(this).prev().find(".child:gt(2)").slideToggle(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":visible"))
      $(obj).text("hide");
    else
      $(obj).text("show more");
  });
});
```

[**Edited Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/188/)

Note that, you need to use the call back function of `slideToggle` to change the text, since `slideToggle` is asynchronous.

[**Final Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/191/)

Comment: Original fiddle and edited fiddle are same links. Please correct

Comment: Thanks. Is there a possibility to hide text `show-hide` with your method, if `div`s are less than 3?

Comment: `if (!divs.length)` - I guess this way :) Thanks for support!

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it with css:

```
.parent div:nth-child(n+4) {
  display: none;
}
```

and use jquery to toggle the class to make it visible/hidden.

```js
$('.parent').filter(function(){
  return $(this).children().length <= 2;
}).next('.showhide').hide();


$('.showhide').click(function() {
  $(this).text(function(i, txt) {
    console.log(txt);
    return txt === "Show"  ? "Hide" : "Show";
  });
  $(this).prev('.parent').find('div:hidden, div.show').toggleClass('show').stop().slideToggle();
});
```

```css
span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.parent div:nth-child(n+4) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
</div>
<span class="showhide">Show</span>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
</div>
<span class="showhide">Show</span>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>
<span class="showhide">Show</span>
```